# How do I create a promise chain in js shaped like a diamond

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I'm stuck with promises.

Say my program structure is like this

```
            Func A             //gets data then passes to I1 and J2
         /          \
      Func I1      Func J1     //then route I & J run without interaction
        |            |
      Func I2      Func J2     
         \          /
             Func B            //Func B gets both the result of both
```

I'm have a bit of trouble getting this to work.
I'm so far as

```
  getdata.then(data=>{
      var methods = Promise.all([
        funci1.x(data).then(output=>{
          funci2.x(output)
        }),
        funcj1.x(data).then(output2=>{
          funcj2.x(output2)
        })
      ])
      methods.then(([a,b])=>{
        console.log(a,b);
      })
  })
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help?

Comment: Main problem is your use of arrow functions. To clarify, `() => { ... }` executes the code within the braces and only returns a value if there's an explicit `return` statement. `() => statement` on the other hand implicitly returns the result of `statement`

Comment: looks more like a trapezoid (Simpsons reference)

Answer (score 3):

You don't return anything that can be casted to a `Promise` in your two `then()` callbacks, so change it to this:

```
getdata.then(data => {
  var methods = Promise.all([
    funci1.x(data).then(output => funci2.x(output)),
    funcj1.x(data).then(output2 => funcj2.x(output2))
  ])
  methods.then(([a, b]) => {
    console.log(a, b);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally find promises written this way easier to identify what is going on.

```
const funcJ1 = (num) => {
  num = num + 1;
  return funcJ2(num);
}
const funcJ2 = (num) => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    num = num + 1;
    resolve(num);
  })
);

const funcI1 = (num) => {
  num = num + 1;
  return funcI2(num);
}
const funcI2 = (num) => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    num = num + 1;
    resolve(num);
  })
);

const funcB = (result) => {
  let total = 0;
  total = total + result[0]; // first promise result
  total = total + result[1]; // second promise result
  console.log(total); 
};

const funcA = (x) => {
    const promises = [];
    promises.push(funcJ1(x));
    promises.push(funcI2(x));
    Promise.all(promises).then((res) => {
      funcB(res); // done with I and J
    }).catch((e) => {
      throw e;
    });
}

funcA(1);
```

funcJ1 and funcI1 will both run in parallel and funcB will run once funcJ2 and funcI2 has completed.

see this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6fvLw8wv/

Comment: how do i get j1 and i1 to run from the data of func a

Comment: I have modified and added an argument to funcA which gets passed around. hope that helps.